# steganography for audio watermarking

Tags: java, mp3, watermark, steganography

anyone can help me, I'm working on watermarking application for mp3 files with algorithms "echo data hiding". I do not understand to make this algorithm with java or matlab. I hope anyone can help by explaining this algorithm, or give examples with source code.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this paper brings some light in the darkness: [Watermarking](http://www.arehna.di.uoa.gr/thesis/uploaded_data/Audio_Watermarking__Steganalysis_Using_Audio_Quality_Metrics__and_Robust_Audio_Hashing_2005_thesis_1208256475.pdf)

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I am still confused with echo hiding algorithm, the paper's not too clear echo hiding method in particular, only provide an explanation in general terms.

Answer (score 0):

[Binary Universe](http://binary-universe.net/index.php?article=8&language=e) gives an overview of stenography in general and has a section on audio, although it doesn't deal with mp3. I'm not sure how feasible stenography is for a lossy format such as mp3. I assume you would have to add it after the compression has taken place.

Comment: at the site, explains the working process of the LSB algorithm is not echo hiding.
echo hiding if I am not mistaken, using the signal from the mp3 file that will be in the watermark. I do not know how to process the signal in java to create algorithms echo hiding.